# Integral involving sigma and pi series

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Please help me solve this integral.

$$\int_0^1\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (x+i)\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{x+j} \right)\,dx$$

Edit: I tried opening up the series and forming this into a coefficient of a polynomial to solve further. Can't seem to find a pathway.

It would be helpful if I get a solution without involving Gamma notation and other complicated integral methods.

Comment: What have you tried? Please give some context.

Comment: I tried using opening the series and then separating terms. Also tried forming this into a coefficient of a polynomial to solve further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that using the product rule,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{x+j}\prod_{i=1}^n (x+i)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\prod_{i=1}^n (x+i)
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{x+j}\prod_{i=1}^n (x+i)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\left.\prod_{i=1}^n (x+i)\,\right|_0^1\\
&=(n+1)!-n!\\[9pt]
&=n\cdot n!
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

The integrand appears to have closed form

$$(H_{n+x}-H_x)(1+x)_{(n)},$$

where $H_x$ is the "$x$-th" [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $(y)_{(n)}$ is the [Pochammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Indefinite integration gives

$$\int (H_{n+x}-H_x)(1+x)_{(n)}dx=(1+x)_{(n)},$$

so we end up with

$$\int_0^1(H_{n+x}-H_x)(1+x)_{(n)}dx=\Gamma(2+n)-\Gamma(1+n)=n\cdot n!,$$

assuming $n$ is a positive integer.

I'll leave it to you to prove the details, or arrive at the same result by different means.

---

For another way, we can see a pattern in the integrand if we expand for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$

$$n=1\implies f(x)=1$$
$$n=2\implies f(x)=(x+1) (x+2) \left(\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$$
$$n=3\implies f(x)=(x+1) (x+2) (x+3) \left(\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$$
$$n=4\implies f(x)=(x+1) (x+2) (x+3) (x+4) \left(\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{1}{x+4}+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$$

So expanding the brackets you see you end up with a sum of products of factors, with one factor missing from each term. Maybe you could somehow formalise that and use that? You could also try integration by parts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am afraid I don't know about the gamma notation. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: If I were you I'd let $n=1$ to see what the integrand is. Then let $n=2$ to see what that integrand is. Then $n=3$... and see if you can spot a pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I just used by-parts and got the integral. Should I write my solution to my own question? New to Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ChitraVenkat [We encourage it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @ChitraVenkat yes, if you have solved your question and nobody else has posted the same answer, post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBHDf.jpg

Here is the solution using integration by parts.

Comment: Good proof; just a couple of proof-writing tips.

(1) We prefer it written in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) rather than unsearchable images.

(2) You should also write $\int\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+x}dx$ as $\int_0^x\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+y}dy$, partly to make it definite, partly to not use $x$ to represent multiple dummy variables in one expression.